Replacing stable diffusion v2.1 text encoder with image encoder
I'm trying to replace the text encoder of Stable Diffusion with a corresponding image encoder, so that I can feed images instead of text. The stable diffusion hugging face documentation says that it uses pretrained text encoder from OpenCLIP ViT/H model. Since the text encoder and image encoder of CLIP share the same latent space, I can easily replace the text encoder with image encoder and the model should work fine without any further training.
However, the text embeddings I am getting from Stable diffusion text encoder and the OpenCLIP ViT/H text encoder are different.
I get the below from stable diffusion text encoder
prompt = 'dress, long sleeve'

model_key = "./models--stabilityai--stable-diffusion-2-1-base/"
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_key, torch_dtype=self.precision_t)
self.tokenizer = pipe.tokenizer
self.text_encoder = pipe.text_encoder
inputs = self.tokenizer(prompt, padding='max_length', max_length=self.tokenizer.model_max_length, return_tensors='pt')
embeddings = self.text_encoder(inputs.input_ids.to(self.device))[0]

I get the below text embeddings using OpenCLIP text encoder
model, _, preprocess = open_clip.create_model_and_transforms('ViT-H-14', pretrained='laion2b_s32b_b79k')
model.eval()
tokenizer = open_clip.get_tokenizer('ViT-H-14')
text = tokenizer([prompt])
text_features = model.encode_text(text)

A main difference is that the embeddings from stable diffusion text encoder is of size (1, 77, 1024), whereas text_features from OpenCLIP text encoder is of size (1, 1024).
I have two questions?

What text encoder from OpenCLIP should I use to get the same embeddings as Stable diffusion text encoder?
What image encoder corresponds to the text encoder in stable diffusion? i.e. which image encoder shares the same latent space as the text encoder?

